# Jquery plug-in not loading when ajax has loaded the page

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, smooth-scrolling

I've been working on this code for awhile. I'm trying to implement the SmoothDivScroll jquery plug-in once the gallery page has been loaded with ajax. Here is my js with ajax. Please note that the smoothdivscroll works fine without loading the gallery with ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.more').live('click',function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'380px'},function(){
            $('#ajax').html('<img class="loader" src="images/loader.gif" alt="">');
            $('#ajax').load('content.php #'+href, function(){
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn().highlightFade({color:'#717171'});
            });
        });
        return true;
    });

    $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: true,
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
        autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
    });

});
```

UPDATE: although @Mathletics answer did get the plug-in to load by calling it in the callback, the smoothscrollingdiv is not so smooth. The pictures are not inline and the sliding is very jerky. It works perfectly fine without loading it by ajax. Below I provided links, of how it looks like with ajax and without.

Ajax Loaded: [select gallery from the menu](http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/~nguyen9/final/#gallery)

No Ajax: [This is how the gallery is supposed to be](http://mobile.sheridanc.on.ca/~nguyen9/final/content.php)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `smoothDivScroll` call into your callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.more').live('click',function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'380px'},function(){
            $('#ajax').html('<img class="loader" src="images/loader.gif" alt="">');
            $('#ajax').load('content.php #'+href, function(){
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn().highlightFade({color:'#717171'});
                    $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                    mousewheelScrolling: true,
                    manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                    visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
                    autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
                });

            });
        });
        return true;
    });


});
```

Comment: The plugin loaded, but isn't scrolling properly.